Помогите разобраться с потоками в C c WinAPI
Итак, имеется вот такой код, на который ругается VS, в чем может быть проблема?
# include <windows.h>
# include <stdio.h>
DWORD WINAPI ThreadMethod(LPVOID){
    printf("Поток работает\n");
    return 0;
}
int main(){
    DWORD id;
    HANDLE th = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadMethod, NULL,
    CREATE_SUSPENDED, &id);
    printf("Main: запускаем поток\n");
    ResumeThread(th);
    printf("Main: поток запущен\n");
    getch();
    return 0;
}


Что значит «ругается»?

Не понятно причем здесь с++ и указание си...

Компилируем. Получаем сообщение об ошибке C2055. Открываем соответствующую страницу и смотрим:

ANSI C требует именовать формальные параметры, если они не является void или многоточием (...).

Исправляем
DWORD WINAPI ThreadMethod(LPVOID){

на
DWORD WINAPI ThreadMethod(LPVOID P){

и с двумя предупреждениями все работает.
Встречный вопрос: что помешало вам выполнить указанные выше действия?
